# Bash: receive messages from background process

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, background-process

I'm sending data via `cansend` to vcan0, at the same time I'm listening to messages that has been send to vcan0 via `candump vcan0`.

For some reason, i won't receive any messages, when sending data to `vcan0` through the script, but when i send data through terminal, the script receives data, somehow.

```
cansend vcan0 004#0152FEE400000000 # sending data to vcan0
while true;
do
  msg_candump=$(candump vcan0) # read vcan0
  if [[ ${#msg_candump} > 1 ]]; then #received msg
    echo $msg_candump
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the job:

```
while true;
do
  cansend vcan0 '004#0152FEE400000000'
  sleep 1
  msg_candump="$(candump vcan0 -n 1)" # read vcan0
  if [[ ${#msg_candump} > 1 ]]; then #received msg
    echo $msg_candump
    msg_candump=${msg_candump// /} # leerzeichen entfernen
    msg_candump=${msg_candump:19:8} # substring holen
    msg_candump=${msg_candump,,} #lowercase
    if [[ $msg_candump != `git log -1 --format="%h"`0 ]]; then
      echo "git pull"
      #git pull
      break
    fi
  fi
  sleep 0.025
done
```